# There are exactly 2 equivalent classes of time-like vectors in a Minkowski space.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, mathematical-physics

This is a purely mathematical question (I am starting to study Minkowski spaces and I don't know how to prove that there are only 2 time-orientations).

Let $V$ be a vector space and $(,):V\times V\to\mathbb{R}$ be a non-degenerated, bilinear, symmetric form. Suppose $T=\{v\in V:(v,v)<0\}$ is non-empty (therefore $(,)$ is not an inner product but a pseudo inner product). (This is the set of time-like vectors).

On $T$ the following equivalent relation is defined: for $u,v\in T$, $u\sim v$ iff $(u,v)<0$.

Prove that there are only two equivalence classes, i.e. show that if $u,v,w\in T$, such that $(u,v)>0$ and $(u,w)>0$, then $(v,w)<0$.

Comment: $~\sim$ isn't an equivalence relation (it isn't reflexive). To fix that you need to replace $<$  by $\le$ in the definition of $\sim$. Having done that you still have to allow for the possibility that $T$ could be empty (which happens if $(,)$ is positive definite. Having excluded positive definitive forms, then you have exactly two equivalence classes: $(u, v)$ is either non-negative or not.

Comment: @RobArthan, you're right. I am interested in the case where $T$ is nonempty (edited the question). In that case, the relation $\sim$ is reflective. However, your argument to prove that there are 2 equivalent classes is incorrect. The fact that $(u,v)$ is positive or negative only means that $u$ and $v$ are in the same equivalence class or not. But this does not prove that cannot exist more than 2 equivalent classes.

Comment: $\sim$ still is not necessarily an equivalence relation. Take $V=\mathbb{R}^2,$ $(u,v)=-\langle u,v\rangle.$ Now try $u=(1\; 2)^T,$ $v=(1 \;0)^T,$ $w=(1 \; -2)^T.$ You get $u\sim v,$ $v\sim w$ but $u\not\sim w.$

Comment: I think the following condition is missing: There are no two time-like vectors $u$ and $v$ for which we get $(u,v)=0.$ With this additional condition, the statement can be proven.

Comment: @ReinhardMeier if we use your proposed condition, how it can be proven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it has already been shown that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation (as it is part of the question, I assume it is true), and if we introduce the additional condition $(u,v)\neq 0\;\forall\, u,v\in T,$ then the statement can be proven as follows:

Take an arbitrary element $u_1$ of $T.$

It can easily be seen that $-u_1\in T,$ because $(-u_1,-u_1)=(-1)(-1)(u_1,u_1)=(u_1,u_1),$ due to the bilinearity of $(\, ,\,).$

The equivalence class of all elements in $T$, which are equivalent to $u_1,$ is $T_1$. If $v\in T$ is not an element of $T_1,$ then $(u_1,v)>0.$ We explicitly excluded the possibility $(u_1,v)=0.$ But $(u_1,v)>0$ means $(-u_1,v)<0.$ So each element of $T,$ which is not equivalent to $u_1,$ is necessarily equivalent to $-u_1,$ which means that we have exactly two equivalence classes, one with the representative $u_1$ and one with the representative $-u_1.$